# Exception raised using XQSharp with transforms that use http://exslt.org/dates-and-times

Tags: xslt

We have been using MvpXslTransform to perform transforms on using a relatively complex set of XSLT files.  In an attempt to improve the performance of the transforms, I am evaluating the XQSharp library.

Unfortunately, when I call ApplyTemplates to perform the transformation, the following exception is raised:

> No implementation was found for extension function 'seconds' in
>   namespace 'http://exslt.org/dates-and-times' with arity 1.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, XQSharp does not natively support the EXSLT functions, which are a set of functions designed to extend XSLT 1.0.  These are not included as they are not standard XSLT functions and have mostly been superceded with XSLT 2.0

Have a look at the `fn:seconds-from-date`, `fn:seconds-from-dateTime`, `fn:seconds-from-time`, `fn:seconds-from-duration`, one of which probably does what you want.

Alternatively, it would be easy to implement this function in XPath 2.0 as an `xsl:function` in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could modify the [implementation](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/64156#258411) of EXSLT from Mvp.Xml and wrap it up as an [XQSharp native module](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/doc/2.3/f37d7e2c-7304-4ad6-80b4-c54d4faa7c9b.htm#native).